# Wifi dongle driver compliation and installation

Tags: wireless

I am trying to install a USB wifi dongle on my Ubuntu laptop and I am loosing the battle so I need some help guys. See details below.

Wifi dongle:  AWUS036NEH by ALFA Network. I have the driver for this device but I can’t get it to complie.

According to what I see in the Makefile the driver code was written for a 2.6 linux kernal. I am running version 4.8.0 so that may be an issue. I have Ubuntu 16.04.4 running and all updates to the OS and the GCC compiler have been installed. Below I have the warnings and errors from the compiler. I don’t know if they can be fixed or not. I took two C programming classes in college and worked as a C programmer for about a year after graduation but that was 30 years ago or so. So, if they can be fixed I could probably pull it off with a little help.

```
/home/bill/Share/AWUS036NEH/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c:1459:32: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
      DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("AES_Key_Wrap: allocate %d bytes memory failure.\n", sizeof(UINT8)*PlainTextLength));


    home/bill/Share/AWUS036NEH/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.c:3142:34: error: passing argument 2 of ‘hex_dump’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
    hex_dump("null frame before", &longValue, 4);

/home/bill/Share/AWUS036NEH/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/include/os/rt_linux.h:787:29: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘RTUSBReadMACRegister’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  RTUSBReadMACRegister((_A), (_R), (PUINT32) (_pV))
                             ^


cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:289: recipe for target '/home/bill/Share/AWUS036NEH/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/bill/Share/AWUS036NEH/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.o] Error 1
Makefile:1491: recipe for target '_module_/home/bill/Share/AWUS036NEH/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/bill/Share/AWUS036NEH/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-41-generic'
Makefile:388: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

I downloaded the driver you provided a link to but when I try to compile I get similar errors to the original code. Damn!

Here is output from the lsusb and lsmod | grep rt commands!

```
bill@hacker1:~/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022_mod-master/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022$ lsusb
```

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b1d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd CNF9055 Toshiba Webcam
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 3938:1032
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

bill@hacker1:~/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022_mod-master/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022$ lsmod | grep rt

rt2800usb              28672  0
rt2x00usb              24576  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              94208  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              57344  3 rt2800lib,rt2800usb,rt2x00usb
rtl8192ce              57344  0
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8192ce
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_pci,rtl8192ce,rtl8192c_common
mac80211              761856  6 rt2800lib,rtl_pci,rtl8192ce,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rtlwifi
cfg80211              581632  3 rt2x00lib,mac80211,rtlwifi
parport_pc             32768  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
bill@hacker1:~/Downloads/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022_mod-master/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022$

Comment: I am quite certain that a circa-2012 driver file is too old to compile on a modern 2017 kernel. Please edit your question to add the result of: `lsusb` and we'll look for a better way. "... the driver code was written for a 2.6 linux kernal. I am running version 4.8.0 so that may be an issue. " Absolutely!!!

Comment: Try this community modified driver: https://github.com/maroviher/DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022_mod

Comment: @Hydranix looks like my Ubuntu 18 (4.15.0-88-generic #88-Ubuntu) is too new, since make fails with errors.